Flyout drawer menu not sized correctly in RTL language (Android)
in a Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2662 version app, using FlyoutPage, the drawer menu pops from the right as expected but it's not completely shown or it even has a gap in some scenarios. The following picture holds a LTR drawer and a RTL drawer. Notice the left/right margin for the icons respectively....................

The problem is in Xamarin.Forms because if I just downgrade Xamarin.Forms to the previous version 4.6, the drawer menu is completely shown.
Does someone know a solution or workaround?
Thanks!

Did you use the FlyoutPage or the Shell?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Sorry I missed giving this information, I'm using FlyoutPage. I'll update the question.

I have tested with a new flyout page. But I can't reproduce your problem. The flyout in my project is same between rtl and ltr.

When I have a moment I'll try to create a basic reproduction project. But there's definitely a wrong setting of the X position of the drawer page.

Sorry for my careless. I forget upgrade the Xamarin.Form package to version 5.0.0.2662. In version 5.0.0.2196, they are same and in version 5.0.0.2662, I met your problem.

Cool, glad to hear you can also reproduce it : )

I found a workaround inspired on this. Basically I have a base FlyoutPage for my app where I can override the OnSizeAllocated() method and reestablish the position of the Flyout page (it's a property of the FlyoutPage) when in Android and RTL locale:
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android &&
        FlowDirection == FlowDirection.RightToLeft)
    {
        Flyout.TranslationX = width - (Flyout.Width + 64 + FlyoutBounds.X);
    }
}

What I still don't know and would like to clarify is the 64 offset. It was 'calculated' by the person who originally posted the workaround in github but not sure if it's just a trial and error finding or if there's some logic behind. Nevertheless, and curiously enough, this workaround works for all Android devices I've tested.

Actually, you can check the last comment in the link you provide. In addition, the xamarin project template's default version is 5.0.0.2196. You don't have to use the last version. Finally, the xamarin support will end on 1 May, please consider upgrade the project to maui.

Thanks for the suggestion to downgrade XF version but we probably going to stick with the latest version and the workaround. For various reasons, the project I'm working on won't migrate to MAUI yet.
